# Delete in Binary search tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have implemented BST in C. Insert and lookup works fine. But delete has issues when deleting the root node. I'm not able to free the pointer to the root node. I could if I pass it as a double pointer, but I wanted to keep the code simple without using double pointers. Here I do NOT have a head pointer which points to the root node. Should I use a head pointer to the root node?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data=data;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;
    return(node);
}

static int lookup(struct node* node,int target)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return(0);
    }
    else
    {
        if(target == node->data)
        {
            return(1);
        }
        else
        {
            if(target < node->data)
            {
                return(lookup(node->left,target));
            }
            else
            {
                return(lookup(node->right,target));
            }
        }
    }
}


struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return(newNode(data));
    }   
    else
    {
        if(data < node->data)
        {
            node->left =insert(node->left,data);
        }
        else
        {
            node->right=insert(node->right,data);
        }
        return(node);
    }
}

struct node* delete(struct node* node, struct node* pnode, int target)
{
    struct node* rchild;
    struct node* rchildparent;
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return(pnode);
    }
    else
    {
        if(target == node->data)
        {
            if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) //leaf node
            {
                if(pnode == NULL) //special case deleting the root node
                {
                    free(node);
                    return(NULL);
                }
                if(pnode->left == node)
                {
                    pnode->left = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    pnode->right = NULL;
                }
                free(node);
                return(pnode);
            }
            if(node->left ==NULL ) //one child
            {
                if(pnode == NULL) //deleting root having no left child
                {
                    struct node* temp = node;
                    node = node->right;
                    free(temp);
                    return(node);
                }
                if(pnode->left == node)
                {
                    pnode->left = node->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    pnode->right = node->right;
                }   
                free(node);
                return(pnode);
            }
            if(node->right ==NULL ) //one child
            {
                if(pnode == NULL) //deleting root having no right child
                {
                    struct node* temp = node;
                    node = node->left;
                    free(temp);
                    return(node);
                }
                if(pnode->left == node)
                {
                    pnode->left = node->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    pnode->right = node->left;
                }   
                free(node);
                return(pnode);
            }

            //two children case
            rchild = node->right;
            rchildparent=node;
            while(rchild->left != NULL)
            {
                rchildparent=rchild;
                rchild = rchild->left;
            }
            node->data=rchild->data;
            if(rchildparent == node)
            {
                //rchildparent->right=rchild->right;
                node->right=rchild->right;
            }
            else
            {
                //rchildparent->left=NULL;
                rchildparent->left=rchild->right;
            }
            free(rchild);
            if(pnode ==NULL) //root node
            {
                return(node);
            }           
            return(pnode);
        }
        else
        {
            if(target < node->data)
            {
                delete(node->left,node,target);
                return(node);
            }
            else
            {
                delete(node->right,node,target);
                return(node);
            }
        }

    }

}
void printinorder(struct node* node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }   
    printinorder(node->left);
    printf("%d\t",node->data);
    printinorder(node->right);
}
int main()
{
    clock_t start,end;
    struct node* root = newNode(3);
    insert(root,7);
    insert(root,7);
    insert(root,7);
    printinorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    root = delete(root,NULL,6);
    printinorder(root);
    printf("\n");
}
```

EDIT:
Fixed the code as per @`modifiable lvalue` suggestion. Now is there a way I can improve the delete logic?

Comment: I guess there is no issue with the `malloc` in function `newNode`. The issue is in the `delete` function where I'm freeing a local copy of the pointer to the root node

Comment: You will need a special ROOT pointer which needs to be passed to the `delete` function. Another solution could be to write a non-recursive `delete` function and cause it to return a `node*` which would be the new root.

Comment: @Koushik What are you talking about? Aside from the potential NULL dereference when malloc fails, newNode is fine.

Comment: If you mean a headPtr would be a member in each node, then probably no. A parent ptr would be advisable -- and one can check for rootnode when parent==this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd return the head node from delete, and manage the head in your main function like: `root = delete(root, NULL, 10);`, and I'd do the same for insert: `root = insert(root,/*...*/);`, as it sort of half looks like you've done...

Comment: Thanks. This is simple and elegant. I made the change and it works fine for the case where I delete the root.

Comment: I think what I like most about this is that it's clear to other people that `head` may indeed change. I like to do this for any functions that can cause `head` to change (in other situations, eg. linked lists, queues, etc, too). That way, it seems far less likely that problems of dangling pointers will crop up in group projects and commercial environments. It might also be an opportunity to balance your tree, in this case.

Comment: One think which I still don't like in my `delete` is that each time I check for the special case of root being deleted. Can I somehow avoid it to improve performance?

Comment: @arunmoezhi In my first edit to your code, I removed unnecessary whitespace from the `delete` code: http://ideone.com/1yVNEP I found by removing the recursive elements, and working in terms of `child`, `branch` (a pointer, initialised to `&node`, but set to point to the branch taken during the search) and `parent` instead of `node` and `pnode` I could remove that test and many others to form this (untested) code: http://ideone.com/HpAOAP

Comment: Thanks for spending your time debugging my code. Actually I did some debugging as well. Was having issues with the recursive return. So I modified it. Now it works of almost all cases. But I'm not sure if I missed any..

Answer (score 0):

private DataNode delete(DataNode root,int dValue){

```
DataNode temp=null;
if(root!=null){
    if(dValue<root.value){
        root.left=delete(root.left,dValue);
    }
    else if(dValue>root.value){
        root.right=delete(root.right,dValue);
    }
    else{
           if(root.left==null){
                temp=root.right;
               root.right=null;
               return temp;
           }
           else if(root.right==null){
               temp=root.left;
               root.left=null;
               return temp;
           }

           temp=MinBST(root.right);
           root.value=temp.value;
           //deleting inorder successor
           root.right=null;
    }
}
return root;
```

}

private DataNode MinBST(DataNode root){

```
if(root!=null){
    while(root.left!=null){
        root=root.left;
    }
}
return root;
```

}

Go through the link for deletion of node from binary tree

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK3tLMYk3nk

Answer (score 0):

```
//c tree
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct tree_node
{
    struct tree_node*right,*left;
    int data;
};
struct tree_node*savetemp=NULL;
struct tree_node* del(struct tree_node*,int);
struct tree_node* insert(struct tree_node*,int);
struct tree_node* travel(struct tree_node*,struct tree_node*);
void inorder(struct tree_node *);
int height(struct tree_node*);
int noOfNode(struct tree_node *);
void main()
{
    struct tree_node* root=NULL;
    int item,cho;
    clrscr();
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        printf("1.insert 2.delete 3.display 4.no of nodes 5.height 6.exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&cho);
        switch(cho)
        {
            case 1:{
                printf("Enter element to insert\n");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                root=insert(root,item);
            }
            break;
            case 2:{
                printf("Enter element to delete\n");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                root=del(root,item);
                if(savetemp!=NULL)//condition for any break link is present to insert or not
                travel(root,savetemp);//to insert break link during insertion
            }
            break;
            case 3:{
                printf("inorder travel\n");
                inorder(root);
            }
            break;
            case 4:{
                printf("No of nodes are: %d\n",noOfNode(root));
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            printf("height of tree %d",height(root));
            break;
            case 6:
            printf("Exiting");
            break;
            default : printf("wrong cho\n");
        }
    }while(cho!=6);
    getch();
}
void inorder(struct tree_node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d \n", root->data);
    inorder(root->right);
    }
}
struct tree_node* insert(struct tree_node*root,int item)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        struct tree_node* temp;
        temp=(struct tree_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        temp->data=item;
        root=temp;
    }
    else
    {
            if(root->data<item)
            {
                root->right=insert(root->right,item);
            }
            else
            {
                root->left=insert(root->left,item);
            }
    }
    return(root);
}
struct tree_node* del(struct tree_node*root,int item)
{
    if(item==root->data)
    {
        if(root->left==NULL&&root->right==NULL) //no child
        {
            root=NULL;

        }
        else if(root->left==NULL||root->right==NULL) //one child
        {
            if(root->left!=NULL) //left child
            {
                root=root->left;
            }
            else               //right child
            {
                root=root->right;
            }
        }
        else  if(root->left!=NULL&&root->right!=NULL) //both child
        {
            struct tree_node* temp;
            savetemp=root->right->left;
            temp=root;
            root=root->right;
            root->left=temp->left;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            if(root->data<item)
            {
                root->right=del(root->right,item);
            }
            else
            {
                root->left=del(root->left,item);
            }
    }
    return(root);
}
struct tree_node* travel(struct tree_node*root,struct tree_node*savetemp)
{
    if (savetemp != NULL)
    {
        insert(root,savetemp->data);
        travel(root,savetemp->left);
        travel(root,savetemp->right);
    }
    return(root);
}
int height(struct tree_node*root)
{
    int lheight,rheight;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
        else
    {
        lheight=height(root->left);
        rheight=height(root->right);
    }
    if(lheight>rheight)
    {
        return(lheight+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(rheight+1);
    }
}
int noOfNode(struct tree_node *root)
{
static int count=0;
    if (root != NULL)
    {
    noOfNode(root->left);
    count=count+1;
    noOfNode(root->right);
    }
    return(count);
}
```

Comment: Kindly add more details as well